# Definite Integral of bessel function of first kind of order one.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to prove $\int\limits_0^\infty J_1(x)~dx=1$ ?

I got $\int\limits_0^\infty J_1(x)dx=-[J_0(x)]_0^\infty$ .

Please help.

Comment: $J_0(0)=1$ and $J_0(\infty)=0$ could be sufficient.

Comment: I couldn't prove $J_0(\infty)=0$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  the generating function of the Bessel functions, sometimes designated as G(x,t):
$$
\large
e^{\frac{x}{2}[t-t^{-1}]}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(x)t^n\\[3em]
\xrightarrow{x=0} 1 = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(0)t^n = 
\begin{align}&J_0(0) + \\&J_1(0) t + J_2(0) t^2 + ...\\&J_{-1}(0)t^{-1} + J_{-2}(0)t^{-2}+ ...\end{align}\\
$$
now by [equating coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equating_coefficients) we get:
$$
J_0(0)=1\; \wedge \;J_{n\ne 0}(0)=0\\
\rightarrow J_0(\infty)=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\because\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}J_0(x)=0$

$\therefore\int\limits_0^\infty J_1(x)dx=-[J_0(x)]_0^\infty=1$

Comment: I couldn't prove $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(x)=0$